# Why is the behaviour of commands in __init__.py in python packages different from command line?

Tags: python, package, init

Python Newbie.
I am trying to create a python package. The file structure is -

```
+-demo1
    +-nsdemo
        +- __init__.py
        +- bar.py
```

The contents of bar.py are

```
bar_var = 'abc'
```

The contents of __ **init** __.py are

```
print('this is nsdemo')
from nsdemo import bar
```

After adding the path in sys.path, I tried to access bar or bar_var after *import nsdemo*, but the following error occured:

```
>>> import nsdemo
this is nsdemo
>>> bar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'bar' is not defined
```

but when I did the same from command line:

```
>>> import nsdemo
this is nsdemo
>>> from nsdemo import bar
>>> bar
<module 'nsdemo.bar' from 'demo1/nsdemo/bar.py'>
>>> bar.bar_var
'abc'
```

If the code in `__init__.py` is supposed to run when I import the package, why won't it run the way same as the command line?